# Phonegap 3.5.0 removes 9-patchness from my 9-patch splash screen

Tags: android, cordova

I have a 9-patch splash screen, `screen.9.png` for my phonegap app. When I build the android project from the phonegap command line:

```
<phonegap|cordova> <build|run> android
```

The 9-patch PNG is copied to the `drawable` folder in `platforms/android/ant-build/res/drawable`, as expected. **BUT** it's copied **without** the 9-patch marks.

This results is the image being stretched on the device.

Note that:

- the 9-patch works fine (tested with the `draw9patch` tool and in another app.
- if I manually overwrite the PNG in the `drawable` folder and put my original 9-patch in it, it works fine and it doesn't stretch on device! [this is for now the best workaround]

Why is this happening, how is this happening (since I don't have a non-9-patch version in my project) and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I am seeing this exact same behaviour. It was driving me mad until I finally realised that Phonegap was removing my borders. Super super annoying.

Comment: I resolved by having the image of same or less dpi than the target class. If the image was larger, it would get stretched no matter the 9-patchiness.